# Adding "static" functions to a struct

Tags: go

encoding/base64 and encoding/hex both support nearly the same set of functions, but `base64` uses a class-based encoder, whereas hex exports the methods at the top level. Is there a simple way to create a wrapper around hex so that you can work with an abstracted encoding interface? More generally, is there a way to do the equivalent of binding a method to a struct? (e.g., SomeStruct.Encode = hex.Encode)

So far, I had to define functions on a `hexEncoder` struct with the same signature as the `hex` functions.  I created an interface like this:

```
type Encoding interface {
    Decode(dst, src []byte) (n int, err error)
    DecodedLen(n int) int
    Encode(dst, src []byte) // base64 returns nothing, hex returns int
    EncodedLen(n int) int
}
```

which works perfectly with `base64.StdEncoding`, but I wasn't clear on how to wrap the hex methods.  I created an empty struct for hex:

```
// wrap hex encoding/decoding so that it can be used interchangeably with base64 encoding
type hexEncoder struct {}

func (h hexEncoder) Decode(dst, src []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return hex.Decode(dst, src)
}
func (h hexEncoder) DecodedLen(n int) int {
    return hex.DecodedLen(n)
}
func (h hexEncoder) Encode(dst, src []byte) {
    hex.Encode(dst, src) // don't return the int to match Encoding
}
func (h hexEncoder) EncodedLen(n int) int {
    return hex.EncodedLen(n)
}
```

This works, but it's a bunch of extra boiler plate (where all that really needs to be wrapped is `hex.Encode`). Is there a better way to do this?  Ultimately, the goal is to be able to use hex and base64 interchangeably with encoding/decoding, like in something like this:

```
func convert(src []byte, decoder Encoding, encoder Encoding) ([]byte, error) {
    temp := make([]byte, decoder.DecodedLen(len(src)))
    n, err := decoder.Decode(temp, src)
    if err != nil {
        return temp, err
    }
    dst := make([]byte, encoder.EncodedLen(len(src)))
    encoder.Encode(dst, temp[:n])
    return dst, nil
}
```

Comment: This seems more like a feature request than a SO question.  It's probably just an oversight.  Unfortunately the 1.2 feature freeze is in effect, so the earliest it could be added would be 1.3.

Comment: @KyleLemons other encoding packages are set up differently...not clear if there's really a standard setup (aside from an Encoder method that takes a source and destination bytes)

Comment: While the interface you're using may not work for all encodings, there may well be a way that they can be standardized.  Base64 and Hex certainly seem like they could have a standard way to work.  Imagine, for instance, an AppendTo-like method/function that doesn't require knowing the Len.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no better way to implement an interface that dispatches to functions in another package, and to be honest I cannot really imagine how a better way would look like.

What you're saying in that wrapper is:

```
type myType struct{}

func (myType) WhenCalledLikeThis() { DoThat() }
```

Which seems optimal. It doesn't need any backing memory, allows slight changes in naming and return values (as you've done for `Encode`), and dispatches with a single call.